# JQuery validation-input text field to be required if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I have the following checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWeb" name="startClientFromWeb" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWeb" />
```

and the following input text field:

```
<input id="mimeType" name="mimeType" data-bind= "value: MimeType" />
```

This is my js validation code:

```
 $("#franchiseForm").validate({
            rules: {
                mimeType: {
                    required: $("#startClientFromWeb").is(":checked")
                }
            }
        });
```

I want the mimeType input text field to be required only if checkbox is checked. For some reason the above is not working. I am quite new to javascript and jquery. Any help with working example will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add your own custom validation methods to handle things like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("requiredIfChecked", function (val, ele, arg) {
    if ($("#startClientFromWeb").is(":checked") && ($.trim(val) == '')) { return false; }
    return true;
}, "This field is required if startClientFromWeb is checked...");


$("#franchiseForm").validate({  
        rules: {  
            mimeType: { requiredIfChecked: true }  
        }  
 });
```

Comment: I tried your code. It gives me the following error:

"Expected: :"

for this line: mimeType: { requiredIfChecked } 

Can You please give the example in Fiddle ?

Comment: Thank You! The problem was that I am applying the validations on $(document).ready and the value of the checkbox is always false. Now I apply the validations after ko.applyBindings call and it works as expected. Anyway thank You for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Validation will not triger if input is `disabled`. You could use that fact - let textbox be required, but initially disabled, and enable it only when checkbox is checked.

```
$(function () {
   $('#startClientFromWeb').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#mimeType').removeAttr('disabled');                
        }
        else {
            $('#mimeType').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have not disabled the #mimeType input.

Answer (score 0):

**The simpliest way which works:**
`rules : {mimeType:{required:"#startClientFromWeb:checked"}}, messages: {mimeType: {required: 'Repeat checked, To date required'}}`